# Best way to curve parts of an object?

Tags: curve-modifier

I'm making an archway thing and have got stuck trying to only make a certain part (the highlighted faces) of it curve:

[image]

I've used an array and curve modifier to get some little support things to curve correctly, using just one object. The trouble with that is, modifiers affect an entire object, whereas I only want to affect one section of the main arch object.

What is the best solution to this problem? (I'm aware of how bad the... topology(?) is)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe simply create a quarter circle and stick it to the existing topology?

[image]